# "Argument" usage

Tags: verbs

I wanted to know if *argument* could be used anonymously with words like *intensify*. I've seen it used in that way in some cases.

For example, in a game I play, there is an ability called "Argument" and the ability makes other abilities stronger. I've also seen *argument* used in this way on other occasions but I can't think of any specific instances at the moment.

Comment: You can have any rules you want in a game.

Comment: Are you sure you're not thinking of [*augment*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/augment)? ("*to make or become greater in number, amount, strength*") I have never seen *argument* used in the way you describe.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing the word *augment* with the word *argument*. (Or your source is confusing them.)

*[Augment](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/augment)*: To make (something already developed or well under way) greater, as in size, extent, or quantity

*[Intensify](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/intensify)*: To make intense or more intense

In this way, *augment* and *intensify* can be used as loose synonyms.  Though I would caution against any kind of broad-brush comparison; they really are two different words.